# Webservice returns error as a response at some connections

Tags: .net, web-services, iis-7, windows-server

I have a webservice running on iis 7 on a windows server machine. I'm using it for requesting data for an iphone app. It was working perfect for the last 3 years but a month ago it suddenly started to give the following error as a response:

> Server was unable to process request. ---> Access to the temp directory is denied.  Identity 'NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE' under which XmlSerializer is running does not have sufficient permission to access the temp directory.  CodeDom will use the user account the process is using to do the compilation, so if the user doesn't have access to system temp directory, you will not be able to compile.  Use Path.GetTempPath() API to find out the temp directory location.

Colleague who is responsible of networking has fixed the problem, at least we thought so. then we have realized that the problem still occurs at some internet connections. For example when a friend opens the app with 3g connection the response comes correctly but it returns error when it is opened with a wifi connection.

We couldn't find out a reason about why this happens. Is there any who met this problem before has any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong but I believe you will need to add permissions to the IIS user accounts on the temp directory. These accounts (IIRC) are IUSR and IIS_IUSRS.

Comment: Already did this but still some people who has Wifi connection meets with the same problem..